# Prepare a schedule so that all courses are taught in the least time

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I encountered one interview question:
There are some professors, some courses, and some students.
Each professor can teach only a single course.
Each course has a fixed duration(Eg. 10 weeks).
For each professor, you are given time availability schedule(assume week wise).
Each student has a list of courses he wants to learn.
There can be only 1:1 classes, i.e., 1 professor can teach only a single student.
A student can attend only one course at a time.
A professor has to finish teaching a course in a one go.

Your aim is to prepare a schedule so that all courses are taught in the least time.
My Approach: I mentioned that this will be solved via graph theory.Like make a directed edge from teacher to course or teacher to student.But I was not able to solve it completely .
Is my approach correct or is it DP problem?
 Pseudocode or Algorithm suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were asked is a [schedulling problem](http://community.stern.nyu.edu/om/faculty/pinedo/scheduling/sched.pdf), which is a dynamic programming problem. In particular, your problem is what is usally called *FJm|brkdwn,pj=10|Cmax*, wich can be traduced as follow:

- There are m machines (the professors) that can process a part of a job (here, a job is the full teaching of a student) independently and in whatever order. Some machines may process the same part of a job (the same course)
- machines are not continuously available
- the duration of a part of a job (a course) is 10 weeks
- you want to minimize the time completion of all jobs

There exist solvers that are well optimized for schedulling problems, but I am not sure if to model your problem as a scheduling problem and to process it through a shedulling problem solver is what was intended by your job interviewer.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the m-coloring problem. Except here we are asked to return the minimum m. Unfortunately, it's an NP-hard problem.
For the given problem, consider a course as a vertex and edge b/w 2 vertexes if a common student exists or professor is the same.
Now first, find the upper bound of m (minimum colors required) using  [Welsh–Powell Algorithm](http://mrsleblancsmath.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/46119304/vertex%20coloring%20algorithm.pdf) and then we can do a binary search to find which is the smallest value of **m** for which we are able to color all the vertex (with no 2 adjacent vertexes with the same color)  using [Graph Coloring](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-coloring-applications/)